# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'hidden' of object #<HTMLDocument> is not a function jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, parallax.js

I have a site that i use in it flexslider and parallax slider

When i enter to the site sometimes (not always), the slider not appear, but if i refresh the page again it appear.

in the console i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'hidden' of object # is not a function jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2

How can i solve this problem ?!

Thank you

Comment: The best way to solve this problem, is to give us your code or a jsFiddle with your code. Even a link to the site could be useful.

Comment: this is the link: http://www.the-dating-genie.com